# App crash on iOS16 when presenting a QLPreviewController

Tags: ios, uikit, qlpreviewcontroller, ios16, xcode14

When I try to present the QLPreviewController, the app crashes, and I can see the log as shown below.

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[2]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011a0d2378 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001171bebaf objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011a159641 -[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:].cold.1 + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011a163d66 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:].cold.5 + 0
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011a144c7f -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 243
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011a0d0faa +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 49
    6   QuickLookUICore                     0x0000000156e62b45 __49+[QLItem(PreviewInfo) contentTypesToPreviewTypes]_block_invoke + 528
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011a8abf5b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011a8ad5b5 _dispatch_once_callout + 66
    9   QuickLookUICore                     0x0000000156e62933 +[QLItem(PreviewInfo) contentTypesToPreviewTypes] + 46
    10  QuickLookUICore                     0x0000000156e632a0 -[QLItem(PreviewInfo) _uncachedPreviewItemTypeForContentType:] + 117
    11  QuickLookUICore                     0x0000000156e637b6 -[QLItem(PreviewInfo) _previewItemTypeForType:] + 150
    12  QuickLookUICore                     0x0000000156e635bc -[QLItem(PreviewInfo) _getPreviewItemType] + 61
    13  QuickLookUICore                     0x0000000156e4cea3 -[QLItem previewItemType] + 59
    14  QuickLookUICore                     0x0000000156e5476d +[QLItemFetcherFactory fetcherForPreviewItem:] + 90
    15  QuickLookUICore                     0x0000000156e4c575 -[QLItem fetcher] + 44
    16  QuickLook                           0x0000000118c8ad46 -[QLPreviewController previewItemAtIndex:withCompletionHandler:] + 153
    17  QuickLook                           0x0000000118cb26e4 __63-[QLPreviewItemStore previewItemAtIndex:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke + 267
    18  QuickLookUICore                     0x0000000156e49633 QLRunInMainThread + 51
    19  QuickLook                           0x0000000118cb25aa -[QLPreviewItemStore previewItemAtIndex:withCompletionHandler:] + 181
    20  QuickLook                           0x0000000118c8499d -[QLPreviewController internalCurrentPreviewItem] + 222
    21  QuickLook                           0x0000000118ce67e6 -[QLPreviewController(Overlay) _actionButton] + 344
    22  QuickLook                           0x0000000118ce6aab -[QLPreviewController(Overlay) _toolBarButtonsWithTraitCollection:] + 100
    23  QuickLook                           0x0000000118ce4a53 -[QLPreviewController(Overlay) _updateOverlayButtonsIfNeededWithTraitCollection:animated:updatedToolbarButtons:] + 129
    24  QuickLook                           0x0000000118ce40f6 -[QLPreviewController(Overlay) updateOverlayAnimated:animatedButtons:forceRefresh:withTraitCollection:] + 152
    25  QuickLook                           0x0000000118c847c2 -[QLPreviewController _setCurrentPreviewItemIndex:updatePreview:animated:] + 230
    26  QuickLook                           0x0000000118c8a628 -[QLPreviewController reloadData] + 418
    27  QuickLook                           0x0000000118c81529 -[QLPreviewController viewWillAppear:] + 408
    28  UIKitCore                           0x0000000138e03795 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 832
    29  UIKitCore                           0x0000000138e0428b -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 107
    30  UIKitCore                           0x0000000138cd00fc __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke.411 + 1127
    31  UIKitCore                           0x0000000139ca17dd -[_UIAfterCACommitBlock run] + 54
    32  UIKitCore                           0x0000000139ca1cdc -[_UIAfterCACommitQueue flush] + 190
    33  UIKitCore                           0x00000001396fa534 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 782
    34  UIKitCore                           0x00000001396e8ce2 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 96
    35  UIKitCore                           0x000000013971e8dc _afterCACommitHandler + 72
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011a030fe5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011a02b952 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 515
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011a02be9d __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011a02b637 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
    40  GraphicsServices                    0x000000012d00828a GSEventRunModal + 139
    41  UIKitCore                           0x00000001396ea425 -[UIApplication _run] + 994
    42  UIKitCore                           0x00000001396ef301 UIApplicationMain + 123
    43  EAM360Enterprise                    0x0000000100ca713f main + 63
    44  dyld                                0x0000000110eab2bf start_sim + 10
    45  ???                                 0x000000020870652e 0x0 + 8731518254
    46  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[2]'
_LSContextInitReturningError() failed with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10817 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSSchemaConfigureForStore, ExpectedSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0xed662242 5fb7c0a8 1bf3f783 33b5c275 ... 5cef5e61 5d97a96c }, _LSLine=478, WrongSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0x3190f8e7 217931fc b7f7be3d 298bbb9a ... 8472784b 30a84b1d }}
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 857.7 - Device: iPhone 14 Pro Max (090DE6D4-3F15-4A60-ABDD-09BE30F01F89) - Runtime: iOS 16.0 (20A360) - DeviceType: iPhone 14 Pro Max
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: If you want an answer you will have to include the full crash log.

Comment: @ThomasDeniau I have updated it with full crash log, Please check

Comment: Definitely an Apple issue. Please file a bug,

Comment: Yeah, I have already filed.